# C# Dynamic UserControl, Button Click, and Master Pages

Tags: c#, button, dynamic, user-controls, master-pages

Got a very frustrating problem that I'm trying to solve regarding C#.NET's way of handling dynamically added usercontrols.

The basic rundown of my page setup is that I have an ASPX page which has a Master Page. The Master Page has some content placeholders. On the codebehind in the ASPX page, I call the Master.FindControl method to find the content placeholders, and then use the LoadControl method to load a UserControl into the placeholder.

On the UserControl, I have a series of textboxes, and a submit button. In this implementation, when I click on the submit button, and put a breakpoint into the OnClick event, I find that the OnClick event is never called.

However, if, instead of using this approach, I remove the Master Page, and add the content placeholders directly on the ASPX page, then use Placeholder.Controls.Add to add the UserControl instead of Master.FindControl, the button works perfectly.

Does anyone have any suggestions as to how I can resolve this without removing the Master Page?

Comment: Your page should have asp:Content controls referencing the ContentPlaceHolders of the master page. You can add ContentPlaceHolders to this Content elements and add dynamic elements to the new ContentPlaceHolders. This way you should be able to keep master page structure.

Comment: Originally I had the Content controls, but didn't think to add ContentPlaceholders *within* the content controls to add content to. Do you think this would solve the problem? Either way, I'll give it a try.